# How to insert a character in a string with condition?

Tags: string-manipulation, number-representation, insert

Considering we have a string:

```
str = "1a 789 4/7 123/7 asff %$#7 478 9/4"
```

How can I insert `"/1"` for the numbers that are integers, to have the following result:

```
res = "1a 789/1 4/7 123/7 asff %$#7 478/1 9/4"
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `StringReplace[str, WordBoundary ~~ x : DigitCharacter .. ~~ WordBoundary :> x <> "/1"]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis answer?

Comment: @YvesKlett It doesn't quite work as written.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, dang, so close… :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is always one space at a time as shown, or if the number of spaces is irrelevant:

```
str = "1a 789 4/7 123/7 asff %$#7 478 9/4";

StringSplit[str] /. 
  s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, DigitCharacter ..] :> s <> "/1" // StringRiffle
```

> ```
> "1a 789/1 4/7 123/7 asff %$#7 478/1 9/4"
> ```

Or adjusting [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/)'s comment code to work:

```
StringReplace[str, 
 w1 : Whitespace | StartOfString ~~ x : DigitCharacter .. ~~ 
   w2 : Whitespace | EndOfString :> w1 <> x <> "/1" <> w2]
```

> ```
> "1a 789/1 4/7 123/7 asff %$#7 478/1 9/4"
> ```